# Recursive and Recusively enumerable

Tags: formal-languages, recursive-algorithms

{1^n | n finite integer and >1}, is this language recursive?

I'm not sure how to prove that a language is recursive, I only know that there should be a TM that accepts any finite input and then halts, but how can I prove that here?

I tried to set n to various values and clearly all of them will led at the end to 1, so does this mean that it halted and accepted the input?

Comment: At looks as if your language simply contains all strings consisting of an arbitrary number of $1$s, and nothing else. That language is rather trivially recursive - it's even regular. If that's not the language you had in mind, you need to improve your question...

Comment: so if we're making it an automaton the start and the final state would be the same, right?

Comment: Hm, no, because you seem to exclude the empty string and the string containg just a single $1$ - you have $n > 0$ in there. So you need 4 states - an initial one, one for one $1$, one for more than one $1$, and an error state that you go to if you see anything other than a $1$. For a TM, it depends on how you want it to report the result - it could either stop in a specific state, or write some specific output to the tape...

Comment: I have n>1 not n>0

Comment: Yeah, that's what I *meant* to type ;-) Hence the 4 states - for $n > 0$ three would suffice...